# MVC C# show two items from database in one slide carousel

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, carousel

I am able to retrieve data from database and displaying it in Carousel, one item at a time, but my requirement is to show multiple item (2 items) at a time in one slide. I have tried but could not achieve it. Below is my code for reference:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000"
        data-pause="hover" data-wrap="true">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->           
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            @{int i = 0; }
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
               i++;
               var active = i == 1 ? "active" : "";
               <div class="item @active">
                   <img src="@Url.Content(item.AchievementCategory.Cat_Img)" alt="@item.A_Title" class="img-responsive" />
                   <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                       <h5>@item.A_Title</h5>
                       <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                   </div>
               </div>
            }
        </div>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```cs
public ActionResult 
{
    var list = db.Achievements.OrderByDescending(x => x.A_Id).ToList();
    return View(list);
}
```

Comment: My guess is, shouldn't you two divs with an active class?

Comment: Even if I use two div, the item in both the div will be same, the idea is to display separate items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly solution and has redundant code, but works I think.
The idea is to have how many slider containers equal to  models  and each of them has one 'current' element and the next one.
Active class is set on the parent of two items.

The view

```
@model List<WebApplication1.Controllers.ModelModel>;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}


<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @for (var  index=0; index< Model.Count; index++)
        {
            var item1 = Model[index];
                var item2 = Model[index+1<Model.Count?index+1: 0 ];
                var active = index == 0 ? "active" : string.Empty;
           

        <div class="carousel-item @active">
            <div class="wrapper">

            <div class=" half-item">
                <div>@item1.Title</div>
                <div>@item1.Desc </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" half-item">
                <div>@item2.Title</div>
                <div>@item2.Desc </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        
        }
    </div>
</div>


<style>
    .wrapper {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
    }
    .half-item {
        width:49%;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

and controller method (easy part)

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(x => new ModelModel() {
            Title = $"Title{x}",
                Desc =$"Description{x}{x}"
            }).ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, I have worked on it, using your logic it worked. However, I had to made some changes to it. I will update the answer.

Comment: Feel free. Now you see what I meant when I wrote before

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have used the logic suggested by @ benuto and added little bit of modification and it worked. I am posting the answer for if anyone needs it.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="border:2px solid red;">              
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    for (var index = 0; index < Model.Count; index++)
                    {
                        var item1 = Model[index];
                        //var item2 = Model[index + 1 < Model.Count ? index + 1 : 0];
                        var active = index == 0 ? "active" : string.Empty;

                        <div class="item @active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <img src="@Url.Content(item.AchievementCategory.Cat_Img)" alt="@item.A_Title" class="img-responsive" />
                                </div>                             

                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <img src="@Url.Content(item1.AchievementCategory.Cat_Img)" alt="@item1.A_Title" class="img-responsive" />
                                </div>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>

public ActionResult CAchievements()
        {
            var list = db.Achievements.OrderByDescending(x => x.A_Id).ToList();
            return View(list);
        }
```